# Java: Generics in interface and factory

Tags: java, generics, interface, factory-pattern

I have a base class `Plant` from which there are two subtype paths.
`Fruit extends Plant` and `Vegetable extends Plant.` 
`Fruit` and `Vegetable` are also abstract classes and then they further have other classes like `Banana extends Fruit` and `Spinach extends Vegetable`.

Now lets say for example, an operation has to be operation via these classes and there is an interface for the operation. 
The current design is as follows:

I have an interface:

```
abstract class Plant {}
abstract class Fruit extends Plant {}
class Banana extends Fruit {}

public interface PlantWeigher<T extends Plant> {    
    public int weight(T fruit);    
}
```

Then I have:

```
public abstract class FruitWeigher<Y extends Fruit> implements PlantWeigher<Y> { }
```

Then further I have the concrete class:

```
public class BananaWeigher extends FruitWeigher<Banana> {
  public int weight(Banana fruit);    
}
```

Now, as the user who just understands Plant, I would like to get the correct instance of the Weigher and then perform the operation.

So the Factory is as follows:

```
public class WeigherFactory {    
   public static PlantWeigher<? extends Plant> getInstance(Plant plant){
     // based on some logic on Plant argument, I return, lets say:
      return new BananaWeigher();    
   }
}
```

So in the user class, I call the following function:

```
PlantWeigher<? extends Plant> instance = WeigherFactory.getInstance(userPlant);
instance.weight(plant);  // THIS LINE GIVES AN ERROR
```

Could some one please help me understand what is wrong with the design here and also could some one please advice a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: What exception, please

Comment: And how is `plant` and `userPlant` defined?

Comment: Does this code even compile??

Comment: This code can not be compiled

Comment: Why does this question have 7 upvotes? It seems very unclear in its current form.

Comment: I have downvoted, this wont compile.

Comment: I have mentioned that there is a line which gives an error. So isn't is understood that it won't compile via the original Post. And the question is to tackle that error

Comment: "There is an error" is pretty much the most ambiguous problem you can have, a very close second to "it doesn't work". Why don't you extend your question with the actual error that you get?

Comment: @Sunny, your pseudo-code had many issues, which I have corrected. I have also explained how you can fix your error, and your misunderstanding about the use of wildcards in this case, and what to read to try and prevent making the same mistake in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line :

```
 PlantWeigher<? extends Plant> instance = WeigherFactory.getInstance(userPlant);
```

means, "I have a weigher that can weight some subclass of `Plant`, NOT all kinds of plants".  For example, if the factory would return a `BananaWeigher`, it wouldn't make sense to try to weight a `Tomato` with this. 
To achieve what you want you should change the Factory as follows:

```
public class WeigherFactory{

   public static <P extends Plant> PlantWeigher<P> getInstance(P plant){
    // should return a correct Weigher for the subttype of Plant P
            return ...
  }
}
```

Then the calling code would return be like:

```
 PlantWeigher<Banana> instance =WeigherFactory.getInstance(banana);
 instance.weigh(banana)
```

Now you have a specific `PlantWeigher` and you can call it with a specific type

**OR**, if you want to be able to weigh any kind of `Plant` with any kind of `PlantWeigher`, you should then change the latter:

```
 public interface PlantWeigher {
    public int weight(Plant p);
}
```

This ensures that a `PlantWeigher` can weight any plan, wether that makes sens or not.

Comment: but the issue is that the user does not know what type of plant it is. It only has the object of type Plant

Comment: Unfortunately the `WeigherFactory` still shouldn't compile, as `BananaWeigher` is not guaranteed to be a subclass of `PlantWeigher<P>`. eg. if `P` is `Spinach`.

Comment: @Sunny, I added an 'OR' if he wants to do that

Comment: @Dunes, since he gets an instance of P is , he cant find out exactly which type `P` and cast safely, code compiles just fine

Comment: @Chirlo but the issue with the second approach is that when the function is called weight(plant). Here the object would be able to see only the details wrt Plant class and in order to access the Banana functions i would have to type cast it

Comment: @sunny, yes but he needs to choose one or the other. Either weigh specific kinds of plants with all information available, or weigh generic plants with generic information

Answer (score 2):

Your error is presumably something like `The method weight(capture#2-of ? extends Plant) in the type PlantWeigher<capture#2-of ? extends Plant> is not applicable for the arguments (Banana)`.

You can't use a `Banana` with a `PlantWeigher<? extends Plant>` which has a method `int weight(T fruit)`. The `PlantWeigher<? extends Plant>` could in fact be a `PlantWeigher<? extends Orange>`, which presumably can't weigh `Banana`s.

Your simplest solution is to change your factory method to:

```
public static <T extends Plant> PlantWeigher<T> getInstance(T plant) {
```

and use it like this:

```
PlantWeigher<Plant> instance = WeigherFactory.getInstance(myBanana);
instance.weight(myBanana); // No more error
```

This is really all about the **PECS principle**. I recommend you read [The Java Tutorials > Guidelines for Wildcard Use](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html) and [Java Generics: What is PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs).

In general:

- *Producers* return data from a method and can use `? extends X` <sup>†</sup>
- *Consumers* accept data into a method (*via* a method parameter) and can use `? super X` <sup>‡</sup>

In general you cannot use an upper-bounded wildcard type argument (`extends`) with a method that has a parameter with the type of the type argument. The only valid value you can send to your `instance.weight` in this case is `null`.

```
instance.weight(null);  // No more error
```

A type parameter which is invoked with a wildcard with an upper (extends) bound is an "out" variable. This is because the compiler can, at best, guarantee it is some subtype of its bound. In this case the bound is `Plant`. You could therefore *get* a `Banana` from a method `T getTestPortion()` on that same `PlantWeigher<? extends Plant>`, as long as it was originally set with a  `PlantWeigher<Banana>`.

If you were to use a lower bounded wildcard, then the compiler could guarantee that the type argument is some super type of `Plant`, and so it could weigh either `Banana` or `Orange`.

Unfortunately for you a `PlantWeigher<Banana>` and `PlantWeigher<Orange>` don't share some common subtype that you can use - but this does in itself indicate a problem with your design.

<sup>†</sup> *For the type of the method return variable*

<sup>‡</sup> *For the type of the method parameter*

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in some parts of your code you use generics, and in other parts you do not. You can go the unsafe way and have one factory method that returns different types of weigher from one method. However, you'll lose the type safety you get from making your weighers generic. eg.

```
Plant banana = ...;
Plant spinach = ...;
Weigher<Plant> bananaWeigher = WeigherFactory.getInstance(banana);
bananaWeigher.weigh(spinach); // Compiles, but will produce a runtime error!
```

The other way is to make WeigherFactory have different methods for each concrete `Plant` class and to make the code that uses the `WeigherFactory` generic as well. eg

```
public class WeigherFactory {
   public static BananaWeigher getInstance(Banana banana) {
      return new BananaWeigher();
   }
   public static SpinachWeigher getInstance(Spinach spinach) {
      return new SpinachWeigher();
   }
}

public abstract class FactoryUser<P extends Plant> {
    /**
     * Method that knows how to call the appropriate WeigherFactory.getInstance method
     * Defined by concrete implementations that know the full plant type.
     */
    public abstract Weigher<P> getWeigher(P plant);

    // common code for all FactoryUsers
    public void run(P plant) {
        Weigher<P> weigher = getWeigher(plant);
        int weight = weigher.weigh(plant);
        System.out.println("the plant weighs: " + weight);
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Banana banana = new Banana();
        FactoryUser<Banana> factoryUser = new FactoryUser<Banana>() {
            // We know the generic type to be Banana now, so we can call the 
            // appropriate WeigherFactory.getInstance method.
            // This technique is known as double dispatch
            @Override
            public BananaWeigher getWeigher(Banana banana) {
                return WeigherFactory.getInstance(banana);
            }
        };
        factoryUser.run(banana);    
    }
}
```

#### When you don't know the actual type of the Plant (the Visitor Pattern)

We will need one `PlantWeigher` that knows how to weigh all types of `Plant`. It can delegate to specialised weighers if need be. But we need a central weigher as you will not be able to return a specific weigher and use it in a type-safe way. The central weigher will use the [Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) to dispatch the correct method for weighing each type of plant.

First you need a `Visitor` interface and an implementation of that class that knows what to do with each concrete plant class. eg.

```
public interface Visitor<T> {
    public T visit(Banana banana);
    public T visit(Spinach spinach);
}

public class WeighingVisitor implements Visitor<Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer visit(Banana banana) {
        return banana.getBananaWeight();
    }
    @Override
    public Integer visit(Spinach spinach) {
        return spinach.getSpinachWeight();
    }   
}

public class PlantWeigher {    
    public int weigh(Plant plant) {
        return plant.accept(new WeighingVisitor());
    }
}
```

Secondly, you will need to modify the `Plant` base class to define an abstract method that accepts a `Visitor`. Only concrete implementations of `Plant` need to implement this method.

```
public interface Plant {
    public <T> T accept(Visitor<T> visitor);
}

public class Banana implements Fruit {
    private int weight;
    public Banana(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }
    public int getBananaWeight() {
        return weight;
    }
    @Override
    public <T> T accept(Visitor<T> visitor) {
        return visitor.visit(this); // the implementation is always exactly this
    }
}
```

Finally, how to use all this:

```
List<Plant> plants = asList(new Banana(10), new Spinach(20));
PlantWeigher weigher = new PlantWeigher();

int weight = 0;
for (Plant p : plants) {
    weight += weigher.weigh(p);
}

System.out.println("total weight: " + weight); // expect 30
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The only concern is that the user is not aware of the exact type and just knows that the object is of the super type Plant. Thus I would like the factory to take the input as Plant type and then return a Weigher based on that

Comment: The problem with this is you need to be able to use the `Weigher` in a type safe way. However, you will require it to accept an instance of `Plant`, which is not type safe. And therein lies the problem. Thus, you must write one weigher that does run times checks on the plant before dispatchng the correct method to weigh the plant. see https://sites.google.com/site/steveyegge2/when-polymorphism-fails -- "polymorphism only makes sense when the polymorphic behavior is really a behavior of the target. When it's the behavior of the observer [weigher], you need runtime typing".

Comment: Though you could consider using the visitor pattern, but this requires you to change your various `Plant` implementations -- which may either be undesirable or not possible. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern